# Can you grow mushrooms from other mushrooms?

Tags: planting, growth, mushrooms

I saw a video of someone growing mushrooms from burying another mushroom in dirt. However, most other videos show only show that you can grow mushrooms from spawn or spores from a company. Can you actually just bury a mushroom and grow your own? If not is there any way to pull the spore yourself and grow mushrooms? I want to grow mushrooms year after year without buying new spawn every time it runs out.

Comment: Heh heh. I'm flashing on the Leslie Nielson character in "Men With Brooms." https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0263734/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "mushroom", some are not difficult to propagate , many are difficult to propagate. They have specific environmental needs . I have started cominus comatus -shaggy manes -a few places ; they are tolerant of location. I have just tossed the mature mushrooms onto lawns. I have read that shitake grow fairly well on oak wood ( cut branches and trunks). The common ( in US grocery stores) agaricus compestry is grown on artificial manure in caves or dark warehouses.

Comment: So you don’t actually need spawn?

Comment: The mushroom itself is the "fruiting body" , it contains spoors that ,under the right conditions ,grow and produce mushrooms.

Answer (score 2):

In fact you only need to buy mushroom culture once. Then you have so many options to multiply your mycelium and save this culture for years!

If you have:

1. **Mushroom Spores** -> you can make **unlimited liquid culture** (it can be stored for 6-12 month)
2. **Liquid Culture (LC) in syringe or Spore syringe** -> you can prepare **sterile liquid medium and share 1 syringe among 3-5 jars 300-500ml each**, so that you'll get minimum 1 Quart of LC. LC can be stored 6-12 month.
3. **Spawn** -> you can make **Grain to Grain transfer (G2G)** and create more spawn jars/bags. Usually 1 spawn jar/bag turn into 5-10 spawn jars/bags. Spawn can be stored for 3-4 month.
4. You can gather spores from mushrooms and **make a spore print** (for basidiomycetes) and store them up to 5 years !
5. **Working with sterile agar media in Petri dishes:**

- spores on agar
- spawn samples on agar
- mycelium on agar to agar (A2A transfer)
- **cloning (you've asked about)** placing a piece of mushroom tissue on agar medium in order to obtain growing mycelium. This is not strictly related to the colloquial notion of cloning, and is simply a manipulation of the natural asexual reproduction system of fungi.
  Mycelium on agar can be stored in refrigerator ~12 month and even longer.

Then you can use mycelium for mushroom growing any time, any season!

Unfortunately, such method as *'growing mushrooms from burying another mushroom in dirt'* usually don't work due to high risks of contamination (bacteria and molds) or work with extremely resistant species. However burying mycelium (or even wasted mushroom blocks) works much better;)

Actually a lot of nuances depend on the mushroom species and cultivation tek, but basic principles are the same :)

Cheers,
Shroomok